# Disable disable option

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, root-access, disable-app

Is it possible to disable the disable option for a system app?

For example, if I turned Google now launcher into a system app, the disable option is grayed out. However, if I do the same for Google keyboard, option to disable is still there. So is it possible to disable the disable option for an app?

*Note: I have a  rooted Android lollipop device.*

Comment: Any specifics on Why do you want to disable the disable option..? and how did you turn the Google now launcher to an system app?

Comment: @Lucky I want it to appear to be"system default" More of a personal preference than anything technical. Moved the apk to system/app. Please don't give answers like"that is not necessary." All I want to know is if it is possible to disable the disable button.

Comment: It is absolutely possible to disable "Disable" as well as "Force stop" option for a user/system app. E.g. **AFwall+** has an option to become Device Administrator which makes it immune from both of the options. IDK how you can do it but I gave you a lead here.

Comment: @Lucky Other than the method *Andre* used, there are many apps in Play store that claims to make a user app into a system app. It's a common ordeal. :)

Comment: As I thought, it seems like making an app Device Admin is the most popular way of disabling the said options. It is risky but it is the way. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477606/disabling-force-stop-button-in-android) and this [link](http://prashantandroid.blogspot.in/2013/07/disable-force-stop-in-manage.html). Unfortunately, both requires programming the app to use Device Admin API, which may or may not be your goal.

Comment: What I don't understand is how the Google Now launcher has the disable option grayed out, while Google Keyboard doesn't have disabled grayed out, even when they are both in the system/app directory. Not that I am developing an application of my own, but rather I want to make Google Keyboard Un-disable-able.